# 'StaticClass' does not contain a definition for 'Property'

Tags: c#, .net-core

*Edit 2, I'll Rephrase the whole post:*

I have the static class `Project.Shared.Constants` and it has some constants and public getter properties:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace Project.Shared
{
    public static class Constants
    {
        public const RegistryHive HIVE = RegistryHive.LocalMachine;

        /*
        ... more constants
        */

        public static RegistryView RegistryView
        {
            get
            {
                return Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem ? RegistryView.Registry64 : RegistryView.Registry32;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I had a `Project.Infrastructure.RegistryReader`. It exists in the code for quite some time and uses the static class.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using Project.Shared;

namespace Project.Infrastructure
{
    public class RegistryReader
    {
        public string Read(string keyName)
        {
            using var baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Constants.HIVE, Constants.RegistryView);
            using var subRegistryKey = baseKey.OpenSubKey(keyName);

            /*
              Actual access, read, parse
            */

            return resultValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to add a `Project.Infrastructure.RegistryWriter` in the same project and same namespace and use the same statics:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using Project.Shared;

namespace Project.Infrastructure
{
    public class RegistryWriter
    {
        public void WriteEthernetChannelInRegistry(string keyName, string value)
        {
            using var baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Constants.HIVE, Constants.RegistryView);
            using var subRegistryKey = baseKey.OpenSubKey(keyName, writable: true);

            /*
              Actual writing of the registry key
            */
        }
    }
}
```

Locally it works, so it can't be totally wrong. On the build system it fails, but only with the Writer. If I declare the same property locally, then the build finishes and has no issues with the Reader.

It might be something between VS using `msbuild` and the build system using `dotnet build --Release` but I couldn't make it fail locally yet.

*Edit 3, the error I receive is:*

`Error: RegistryWriter.cs(72,99): error CS0117: 'Constants' does not contain a definition for 'RegistryView' [c:\source\...\Project.Infrastructure.csproj]`

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Please show us your code instead of simply explaining what you have. We need to see it to help you.

Comment: The error seems pretty self explanatory. The property doesn't exist, or perhaps it's not static.

Comment: Showing the precise error message would help as well...

Comment: Edited the post with code snippets and the error message. @ProgrammingLlama it exists, it builds and runs locally just fine.

Comment: is `Project.Shared` a separate repo/project? does the build order build this first? has the latest for that project been pulled from version control?

Comment: `msbuild` and `dotnet build` work differently and are not interchangeable